# How to edit the color theme for mathematical operators (+, -, =, .etc) in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to personalize the color theme on Visual Studio Code because I'm used to a certain theme on a another software. So I want to change the color of the mathematical operators (+, -, =, ...).

I tried scrolling through the different options under `workbench.colorCustomizations` and `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` but I can't seem to find anything that changes the color of the operators.

Does anyone know which keyword covers the operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first things you need to do is to find the token name/scopes of the operatos. You can do this by open vscode command palette `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` then search for `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`, check the scopes by moving you caret.

After finding the scope name, open your vscode JSON settings, and create new textMateRules, it's looks like this:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": ["bold.inline.source.post"],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#D55"
                }
            }
        ]
}
```

Reference: [vscode syntax highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide)

Comment: Using `"scope": [keyword.operator]` worked perfectly.